# C++ removing element in map in map

Tags: c++, maps

I have this program in which I store values in a map in this form.

```
map<string, map<int, CItem, cmpByCnt>> m_Items;
```

So if I have two items that have the same name, I save them to the "submap". For example, here I have:

```
map: {
       key: beer map: {key: date: 1470783661 count: 50}
       key: bread map {key: date: 1461538861 count: 0, key: date: 1461970861 count: 80}
     }
```

How can I delete in this submap?

1. For example, if the key (date) 1461538861 with count = 0 delete this record in the submap. But I want to keep key: date: 1461970861 count: 80

so i get

```
map: {
           key: beer map: {key: date: 1470783661 count: 50}
           key: bread map {key: date: 1461970861 count: 80}
         }
```

2. If I want to delete on the base of the outer key, here: beer, so I will also delete the outer map

so i get

```
map: {
               key: bread map {key: date: 1461970861 count: 80}
             }
```

Maybe I'm at least a little understanding. Thank you for all the comments. Complet program https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xzqq36xf

```
class CSupermarket
{
    public:
        CSupermarket();
        CSupermarket& store(const string &name,const CDate &date,const int &cnt);
        map<string, map<int, CItem, cmpByCnt>> m_Items;
};
CSupermarket& CSupermarket::store(const string &name,const CDate &date,const int &cnt)
{
    CItem a(name, date, cnt);
    auto itr = m_Items.find(name);
    if ( itr != m_Items.end())
        itr->second.emplace(a.m_Date.m_Time, a);
    else
        m_Items.emplace(name, std::map<int, CItem, cmpByCnt>{{a.m_Date.m_Time, a}});
    return *this;
}
int main()
{
    CSupermarket s;
  s . store ( "bread", CDate ( 2016, 4, 30 ), 100 )
    . store ( "butter", CDate ( 2016, 5, 10 ), 10 )
    . store ( "beer", CDate ( 2016, 8, 10 ), 50 )
    . store ( "bread", CDate ( 2016, 4, 25 ), 100 )
    . store ( "okey", CDate ( 2016, 7, 18 ), 5 );

// print
        for(auto itr = s.m_Items.begin(); itr != s.m_Items.end(); ++itr)
        {
            cout << itr->first << " ";
            for(auto i = itr->second.begin(); i != itr->second.end(); ++i)
            {
                cout << " date: " << i->first << " count: " << i->second.m_Cnt;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo because I deleted according to the key: beer (outer map)

Comment: Oh, sorry, i misread the dates... Anyhow, if you delete `1461538861` in the submap, `1461970861` will still be there, just like you want.

Comment: yes, but if I delete it too, the whole submap will disappear

Comment: If you delete the last item in the submap, the submap will be empty. It won't disappear. It will disappear only when you delete the key in the outer map. Perhaps a [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) would be a better choice for this?

Comment: multimap is not the best option for me in this program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting an element from a 2d map is almost the same as deleting it from a 1d map. You just want to call `.erase` on the inner map.

Say if you have a 1d map:

```cpp
std::map<int, std::string> m = {
    {1, "one" }, {2, "two" }, {3, "three"},
    {4, "four"}, {5, "five"}, {6, "six"  }
};
```

To delete `{3, "three"}`, you just do:

```cpp
m.erase(3);
```

---

Now if you have a 2d map:

```cpp
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, std::string>> m = {
    {1, {{"en", "one"}, {"es", "uno"}}},
    {2, {{"en", "two"}, {"es", "dos"}}},
    {3, {{"en", "three"}, {"es", "tres"}}},
    {4, {{"en", "four"}, {"es", "cuatro"}}},
};
```

To access the inner map, you would do:

```cpp
m[1];
```

Now, if you want to remove `{"en", "one"}` from it, you just do:

```cpp
m[1].erase("en");
```

And if you want to remove one of the entire inner map, you would do:

```cpp
m.erase(3);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/aqzGTfc37

---

One thing to note is that deleting all elements of an inner map will not automatically delete that inner map from the outer map. To remove all the empty inner maps, you can do:

```cpp
std::erase_if(m, [](auto& item){
    auto& [number, inner_map] = item;
    return inner_map.size() == 0;
});
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hMhMd8Y7b

---

For C++17 and earlier, there isn't `erase_if` function for `map`, so instead, you would do something like:

```cpp
for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end();)
{
    if(it->second.size() == 0)
    {
        it = m.erase(it);
    }
    else ++it;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/aTvPGGT8K

Comment: Is there an alternative to erase_id for -std = c ++ 17 ?

Comment: @Martin88 I've added the alternative to the end of my answer.